# OnResume method throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add an item in the action bar, but when I click on the item from `MainActivity`, it shows a NullPointer exception.
It should start that activity. I have registered that activity in my Android manifest file as well !!
Here is my code.

```
package milind.com.bluetooth_transmission;

public class settings extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView textConnectionStatus;
    ListView pairedListView;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        // Member fields
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        textConnectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connecting);
        textConnectionStatus.setTextSize(40);

        // Initialize array adapter for paired devices
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

        // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
        pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);


    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //It is best to check BT status at onResume in case something has changed while app was paused etc
        checkBTState();

        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();// clears the array so items aren't duplicated when resuming from onPause

        textConnectionStatus.setText(" "); //makes the textview blank

        // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // Get a set of currently paired devices and append to pairedDevices list
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // Add previously paired devices to the array
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//make title viewable
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        } else {
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add("no devices paired");
        }
    }

    //method to check if the device has Bluetooth and if it is on.
    //Prompts the user to turn it on if it is off
    public void checkBTState()
    {
        // Check device has Bluetooth and that it is turned on
        mBtAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // CHECK THIS OUT THAT IT WORKS!!!
        if(mBtAdapter==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            if (!mBtAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my stack trace:

```
07-26 16:42:58.492  18894-18894/milind.com.bluetooth_transmission E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: milind.com.bluetooth_transmission, PID: 18894
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {milind.com.bluetooth_transmission/milind.com.bluetooth_transmission.settings}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2980)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3011)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear()' on a null object reference
    at milind.com.bluetooth_transmission.settings.onResume(settings.java:53)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1241)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6019)
    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2969)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: i guess line 53 is this line mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();

Comment: Your mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter is null when onResume is called. You should either check for it being null or create the adapter in on resume instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override wrong onCreate method. You need override:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Answer (score 0):

When onResume is called all class members are reinitialized to their default values, in this case null.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

> When the user resumes your activity from the Paused state, the system calls the onResume() method.
>   Be aware that the system calls this method every time your activity comes into the foreground, including when it's created for the first time. As such, you should implement onResume() to initialize components that you release during onPause() and perform any other initializations that must occur each time the activity enters the Resumed state (such as begin animations and initialize components only used while the activity has user focus).

Comment: so now what should i do ?

Comment: You should reinitialize the variable or in your case, just delete this line: `mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();`